# Bounded Linear Map on a Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_1,\dots, e_n,\dots \}$ be an orthonormal set. Let $(\alpha_m)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that
\begin{align*}
&Lu = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\langle u,e_m \rangle e_m&
\end{align*}

defines a bounded linear map $L$ on $X$ if and only if $K=\sup_{ m=1}^{\infty} |\alpha_m| <\infty.$

My attempt: Let $K=\sup_{ m=1}^{\infty} |\alpha_m| < \infty$, and we show that $L$ is bounded and linear:
To show that $L$ is linear, let $a, b$ be scarlas and $u, v$ be vectors in $X$, then
\begin{align*}
&L(au+bv)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\langle au +bv,e_m \rangle e_m&\\
&=a\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\langle u ,e_m \rangle e_m+b\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\langle v ,e_m \rangle e_m&\\
&=aLu+bLv&
\end{align*}
This shows the linearity of $T$.

To show the boundedness,
\begin{align*}
&\|Lu\| = \|\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\langle u,e_m \rangle e_m \|&\\
&= \|\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\alpha_m\langle u,e_m \rangle e_m \|&\\
&\leq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_m| |\langle u,e_m \rangle| \| e_m \|&\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_m| |\langle u,e_m \rangle|&\\
&\leq|K| \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} |\langle u,e_m \rangle|&\\
\end{align*}
From here I am not sure how to proced to show the boundedness.
And also I am not sure how to show the converse.
Any feedback will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Bessel's inequality?

Comment: Suppose $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $X.$ Then 

$$u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle u , e_n \rangle e_n,$$

the sum converging in $X.$ Thus the map $Lu=u,$ which is obviously bounded, works with $\alpha_n=1$ for all $n.$ Something is not right here.

Comment: So using Bessel's inequality, we have $\|Lu\| \leq |K|\sum |\langle u,e_m| \leq  |K|\sum |\langle u,e_m|^2 \leq  |K|\|u\|^2 $, then the operator norm is obtained by dividing $\|u\|$ on both sides 
 $\|L\| \leq \sup K \|u\|$???

Comment: Thanks Thomas Shelby, there was a typo in the statement as pointed out by Kavi Rama Murthy,  which I have  finally fixed. The correction i s \sup_{ m=1}^{\infty} |\alpha_m| <\infty.

Comment: @gamma555 If you want to reply to a comment made by a user, please use `@` before their username. Otherwise, they won't get any notification.  Also, see [this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out the result is false as stated. The correct statement is $L$ is a bounded operator iff $\sup_m |\alpha_m| <\infty$.

For a proof you have to recall that $\|v\|^{2} \geq \sum |\langle v, e_n \rangle|^{2}$ for any vector $v$ and any orthonormal sequence $(e_n)$.

From this it follows that $\|Lv\|^{2} \leq M^{2}\|v\|^{2}$ where $M=\sup_m |\alpha_m| <\infty$. Hence $L$ is a bounded operator when $M <\infty$. If $M=\infty$ then $\|L\| \geq \|Le_k\|= |\alpha_k| \to \infty$ so $L$ is not bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have made the correction.